Azure Function fails to start when in cloud
I have an Azure Function, which runs fine locally, when I deploy it to the Azure Portal, it complains that it encountered an "Error while loading functions - Encountered an error (InternalServerError) from the host runtime", as you can see in the screenshot below.

When looking through the logs, there is a lot going on, but some errors seems to occur in a fixed pattern (sorted by time descending):
> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
> An exception occurred while receiving events for Event Hub: sessionmetadataupdated (Consumer Group: 'playbyplayfeedprocessor', Partition Id: '11'); Operation Id: '993c69e4-5b4d-4f71-80fd-61488d3bc08f'. Error Message: 'At least one receiver for the endpoint is created with epoch of '0', and so non-epoch receiver is not allowed. Either reconnect with a higher epoch, or make sure all epoch receivers are closed or disconnected. TrackingId:3b769308-3d08-49e2-bffe-0dc78c637f2a_B12, SystemTracker:metadata-v3-stadium-bb-trackman-dev:eventhub:sessionmetadataupdated~12287, Timestamp:2024-04-18T06:31:52 Reference:b4d803e0-0189-4e21-9401-5a98d268a1a2, TrackingId:cd151c95-2830-4e6d-8b38-0456b41bbbc5_B12, SystemTracker:metadata-v3-stadium-bb-trackman-dev:eventhub:sessionmetadataupdated~12287|playbyplayfeedprocessor, Timestamp:2024-04-18T06:31:52 TrackingId:5909ac77e7c046ea982e531736dbe67d_G0, SystemTracker:gateway5, Timestamp:2024-04-18T06:31:52 (sessionmetadataupdated).  For troubleshooting information, see https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/eventhubs/exceptions/troubleshoot'
> Failed to start a new language worker for runtime: dotnet-isolated.
> Exceeded language worker restart retry count for runtime:dotnet-isolated. Shutting down and proactively recycling the Functions Host to recover
> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'appsettings.Release.json' was not found and is not optional. The expected physical path was '/azure-functions-host/appsettings.Release.json'.

Which could seem to indicate that it cannot find appsettings.Release.json (whether using appsettings.json in Azure Functions is a good idea, is another discussion, for now I have to deal with it). But I have tripple checked that it is copied on both build and publish. And I have checked the artifact produced by the CI/CD pipeline and the file does exist in that.
Here is how it's loaded in my Program.cs file:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using PlayByPlayDataFeed.Function.ServiceConfigurations;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

string environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ??
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not find value for 'ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT' in app settings.");

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((_, configBuilder) =>
    {
        configBuilder
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json",
                optional: false,
                reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true, true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        ServiceConfigurations.ConfigureServices(services, hostContext.Configuration);
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

I am quite sure I am using all the correct packages, according to the Azure Functions Migrations Guide. Here is how it looks in my .csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enabled</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="6.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.15.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
      <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PlayByPlayDataFeed.Common\PlayByPlayDataFeed.Common.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.Development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="appsettings.Production.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="appsettings.Release.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

My settings (I removed the ones that aren't directly related to the functions runtime) are like this:
"APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING": "InstrumentationKey=(...)",
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=(...)",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Release",
"FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~4",
"WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=(...);EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
"WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE": "(...)",
"WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE": "true",
"WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE": "1",
"WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE": "true"

I have read so many posts on SO, Microsoft and Github. But most of them are people having issues when running locally. And if not it was typically because they missed something like FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME, which I don't. Also, what's with the message about missing appsettings.Release.json?
What am I missing here?
Update 1
Here is a screenshot from the build artifact, showing that all possible appsettings.json files are indeed included:
Update 2
It actually works, if I take all the settings from both appsettings.json and appsettings.release.json and put them into the Azure Function App Settings in cloud. So it seems like it for some reason won't read any appsettings file, when running in cloud. Maybe it has to do with it being Linux (my development machine is Windows). Either way, I'm very interested, if someone can tell me why this happens.


What does happen if you run the project locally inn release mode? I'm pretty certain that you are simply missing the release config in your folder. And thats the issue why its not working

@Aaron I have tried setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable to Release when running debug. And pulling all the settings for the function from Azure. It still runs locally.

Just to be sure, try to set the ENVIORNMENT config as optional and see if it runs in azure. From the error message im almost sure that there's an issue. How do you create the release config? Is it present in the directory or do you create it as part of the CI/CD process?

@Aaron it actually seems to get to a different place, if I make the appsettings.env.json optional. However, this still leaves me with the issue, that I acutally need the file. And I still don't get why it's not able to find it, when it's clearly in the build artifact (see update).

I'm sure this is your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59959258/how-to-add-an-appsettings-json-file-to-my-azure-function-3-0-configuration I also would go with the approach to add all variables as Azure App Settings which should be more robust as well and easier to maintain.

@Aaron unfortunately it doesn't help solve the problem on how to get an appsettings.json file to work. But when going with all settings in Azure - and making the appsettings file optional - it actually works.

It's appSettings.Production.json
You have the environment name wrong. You've used the name of a build configuration 'Release' instead of an environment name.
Also, try this.
First enable your access to the advanced tools

portal.azure.com
Go to your function app
Choose "Networking" in the side menu
Click the "Public network access" hyperlink
Click the "Advanced tool site" tab
Add your IP to the list with a high priority (low number)

Next inspect your settings

Go back to the function app
Click "Advanced tools" in the side menu
Follow the link in the page's main content
Click the "Environment" tab to see all the values your function app is using and fix if necessary
Click the "Log stream" tab to view live logs
Restart your function app and observe the logs

You might already know all of this, but I thought I'd outline it just in case there was a small part you didn't know.
Keep in mind that if the app fails gracefully then it will just stop, it won't show an error. e.g.
try
{
  app.Run();
}
catch
{
  // Do nothing
}


I can understand why you think that. But for some reason we have an environment below Production, which is called “Release”. I guess “QA” or “Test” would have been a better name, but I’m not allowed to change that :-(
